# Facing issues in android studio realtime database

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}


android {
    namespace = "com.example.books"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.books"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}
```

```
                                                                                                          when i run my emulator its shows an error like this
```

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

I want to know why that error is occur and what should I do to make sure my emulator runs I get to see my output for the Realtime database. I been tried many ways its still shows like this only. Anyone could help me on this issue?